# AWS Golang SDK V2 IAM service : how to check whether a user is root user or not

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, sdk, amazon-iam

AWS Golang SDK V2 IAM service : How to check whether a user is root user or not ? using golang api. I am using listusers api to list all users and want to do some action based on non root users only. Looking for programmatic SDK golang based solution.

Comment: you should what have you tried, any errors

Answer (score 0):

As part of the `ListUsersOutput` response to `ListUsers` you should see a slice of `User` named `Users`. Each `User` will contain a `UserId`, which in turn contains a `Type` field. This will be set to `Root` if the user is a root user.

Alternatively, you can look at the `Arn` field of each `User` and check if it ends with `:root`, but this is more error prone.

Comment: UserId is a string pointer in the struct "UserId              *string" that value comes out be something like AIDATAJ5WXKUGUFYZPCWW

Comment: Ah, my mistake. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/Using_Identifiers.html . The prefix `AIDA` on that string denotes an IAM user. You may be better off using the `Arn` field on the `User` and checking if it ends with `:root`.